# ORA-00998: "must name this expression with a column alias"

Tags: sql, oracle, create-view, column-alias

I need help with that error
this is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emplpersuc
AS SELECT SUCURSAL.NOMBRE, COUNT(SUCURSAL.NOMBRE) FROM VENTA
JOIN SUCURSAL ON SUCURSAL_CODIGO_SUCURSAL=CODIGO_SUCURSAL
GROUP BY SUCURSAL.NOMBRE
ORDER BY COUNT(SUCURSAL.NOMBRE) DESC;
```

I tried everything in my knowledge, i´m desperate

Comment: the error message says it clear your count needs an alias

Comment: sorry, i´m pretty new to sql and my english is not that good

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you need to make sure your columns all have valid identifiers (and although `COUNT(NOMBRE)` is a valid expression, it is not a valid identifier to name the column in the view).

You can either name it in the view's signature:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emplpersuc (nombre, nombre_count) AS
SELECT s.NOMBRE,
       COUNT(s.NOMBRE)
FROM   VENTA v
       JOIN SUCURSAL s
       ON SUCURSAL_CODIGO_SUCURSAL=CODIGO_SUCURSAL
GROUP BY s.NOMBRE
ORDER BY COUNT(s.NOMBRE) DESC;
```

or with a column alias in the query:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emplpersuc AS
SELECT s.NOMBRE,
       COUNT(s.NOMBRE) AS nombre_count
FROM   VENTA v
       JOIN SUCURSAL s
       ON SUCURSAL_CODIGO_SUCURSAL=CODIGO_SUCURSAL
GROUP BY s.NOMBRE
ORDER BY COUNT(s.NOMBRE) DESC;
```